# Do I need an Array a List?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I am making a program for a game. It takes the level of the class (of which you can have 8 simultaneous different ones of different level). Each class has different values for one Dim I have known as Defense, it has 6 different possibly levels. Each of those 6 levels corresponds with a value based on the level of each class.

I'm almost certain I need an array or a list, I've seen some examples here but I haven't seen something that quite fits my case.

Do I need to have an array within an array? Is that even possible?

I apologize if I'm horrible at explaining what I'm trying to accomplish.

An example would be if the person chose Strong Hero and then chose Level 4. Following that they'd pick Fast Hero and chose Level 5. I'm trying to get it to look at what the value for 4 would be for Strong Hero and the value for Fast Hero, find those and then add them into Def at the end.

Thank you in advance for anyone who is willing to put up with my ignorance!

```
            Dim Def As Integer = 0

            'Declares a single-dimension array of 10 values
            Dim DefLvl(9) As Integer

            Dim DefType As String = ""
            Dim DefLvl1 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl2 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl3 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl4 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl5 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl6 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl7 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl8 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl9 As Integer = 0
            Dim DefLvl10 As Integer = 0

    'This sets the cmblevel.text = to an integer to be multiplied later
            'Level 1
            If cmbLevel1.Text = "1" Then
                Level1 = 1
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "2" Then
                Level1 = 2
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "3" Then
                Level1 = 3
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "4" Then
                Level1 = 4
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "5" Then
                Level1 = 5
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "6" Then
                Level1 = 6
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "7" Then
                Level1 = 7
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "8" Then
                Level1 = 8
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "9" Then
                Level1 = 9
            ElseIf cmbLevel1.Text = "10" Then
                Level1 = 10
            End If

    '
    If cmbClass1.Text = "Strong Hero" Then
                HD1 = "8"
                DefType = "Avg+"
                DefLvl1 = 1
                DefLvl2 = 2
                DefLvl3 = 2
                DefLvl4 = 3
                DefLvl5 = 3
                DefLvl6 = 3
                DefLvl7 = 4
                DefLvl8 = 4
                DefLvl9 = 5
                DefLvl10 = 5

            End If

        'This formula will calculate Defense for each class and level
        If DefType = "Poor" Then
            DefLvl1 = 0
            DefLvl2 = 1
            DefLvl3 = 1
            DefLvl4 = 1
            DefLvl5 = 2
            DefLvl6 = 2
            DefLvl7 = 2
            DefLvl8 = 3
            DefLvl9 = 3
            DefLvl10 = 3
        ElseIf DefType = "Avg" Then
            DefLvl1 = 1
            DefLvl2 = 1
            DefLvl3 = 2
            DefLvl4 = 2
            DefLvl5 = 3
            DefLvl6 = 3
            DefLvl7 = 4
            DefLvl8 = 4
            DefLvl9 = 5
            DefLvl10 = 5
        ElseIf DefType = "Avg+" Then
            DefLvl1 = 1
            DefLvl2 = 2
            DefLvl3 = 2
            DefLvl4 = 3
            DefLvl5 = 3
            DefLvl6 = 3
            DefLvl7 = 4
            DefLvl8 = 4
            DefLvl9 = 5
            DefLvl10 = 5
        ElseIf DefType = "Good" Then
            DefLvl1 = 1
            DefLvl2 = 2
            DefLvl3 = 2
            DefLvl4 = 3
            DefLvl5 = 4
            DefLvl6 = 4
            DefLvl7 = 5
            DefLvl8 = 6
            DefLvl9 = 6
            DefLvl10 = 7
        ElseIf DefType = "Good+" Then
            DefLvl1 = 1
            DefLvl2 = 2
            DefLvl3 = 2
            DefLvl4 = 3
            DefLvl5 = 4
            DefLvl6 = 4
            DefLvl7 = 5
            DefLvl8 = 6
            DefLvl9 = 7
            DefLvl10 = 7
        ElseIf DefType = "Great" Then
            DefLvl1 = 3
            DefLvl2 = 4
            DefLvl3 = 4
            DefLvl4 = 5
            DefLvl5 = 5
            DefLvl6 = 6
            DefLvl7 = 6
            DefLvl8 = 7
            DefLvl9 = 7
            DefLvl10 = 8
        End If

        'This adds up to all 8 classes' DefLvls
        Def = DefLvl1 + DefLvl2 + DefLvl3 + DefLvl4 + DefLvl5 + DefLvl6 + DefLvl7 + DefLvl8 + dexM
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn about classes.

Comment: Also lookup the `Integer.Parse` and `Integer.TryParse` methods.  There is no need for those `If-ElseIf` blocks.  Besides comparing text is relatively slow.

Comment: You can use either lists or arrays. Lists are a lot easier than arrays if you don't know how many items will be in the list. Yes, you can create arrays of arrays. You can also create lists of lists, arrays of lists, and lists of arrays. If in doubt, try using lists.